# Accordion Up Down Arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a downward arrow when the section is closed and an upper arrow when the section is open - at the right end of the head of each tab in the accordion.

Below is the HTML that I've used. It has for-each loops.

```js
-- Javascript


$(function () {


        $('tr.accordion').click(function () {

            $(this).nextUntil('.accordion').slideToggle(20);

                      
        });
    });
```

```css
td.bg-light-blue{ background-color:rgb(233,242,253) }
.text-mid{ font-size:14px }
```

```html
<div class="box-table" id="div_SummaryReport">
  <table class="research table text-center" id="tblSummary" width="100%">
    <thead style="position:relative;">
      <tr style="position:relative;">
        <th align="center" width="20%" style="position:relative;">&nbsp;</th>
        <th align="center" width="20%" style="position:relative;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Total Calls"> Total Calls</th>
        <th align="center" width="20%" style="position:relative;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Contacted"> Contacted</th>
        <th align="center" width="20%" style="position:relative;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="#of saved calls"> Saved</th>
        <th align="center" width="20%" style="position:relative;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Percent"> Percent %</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model.GroupingData) {
      <tr class="accordion">
        <td class="bg-light-blue text-mid" colspan="5"><span class="text-blue">@item.Key</span></td>

        <td class="bg-light-blue">downarrow</td>
      </tr>


      foreach (var data in item.Value) {
      <tr class="hidden-row">
        <td>@data.Name</td>
        <td>@data.TotalCalls</td>
        <td>@data.Contacted</td>
        <td>@data.Saved</td>
        <td>@data.Percentage</td>
      </tr>
      } }
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

The actual page looks close to this Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jmmanne/35nne25r/ This is sample html without loop

Comment: I have tried using                                                  
        $accordian.find('.accordion-body').slideUp();
         if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
             $(this).next().slideDown();
                   $('h4 span',this).text("Up Arrow");
            }else{
                $('h4 span',this).text("Down Arrow");
            }                 It did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution in fiddle.  simplest method is using a class and a pseudoelement.  you'll probably want to use font-awesome or an image for the arrows, but I just used v and > for example. https://jsfiddle.net/VeritoAnimus/avw0d9j1/1/

CSS Update

```
tr.accordion td:last-child:after { float: right; }
tr.accordion td:last-child:after{ content: 'v';  }
tr.accordion.collapsed td:last-child:after{ content: '>'  }
```

JS Update

```
$(function () {
    $('tr.accordion').click(function () {
                    var acdn = $(this);
        $(this).nextUntil('.accordion').slideToggle({
            duration: 20,
          complete: function () {

                /* if we were just doing one element, we could do a simpler complete function this will only change when the animation completes.  since there's  multiple rows, this would be called multiple times, so that's a pain. hence why I check the row for which way I was going. */

              if($(this).is(':hidden') && !acdn.hasClass('collapsed'))
                acdn.addClass('collapsed');
              else if (!$(this).is(':hidden') && acdn.hasClass('collapsed'))
                acdn.removeClass('collapsed');

          }

        });
        // if you don't care about when it changes, you could just do this instead.
        // $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');

    });
});
```

just realized I did the arrows backwards per your request.  I'm used to seeing > as closed and V as open.  It's an easy enough switch though.

```
tr.accordion td:last-child:after{ content: '>';  }
tr.accordion.collapsed td:last-child:after{ content: 'v'  }
```